# How to make Dynamic menu to perform multi selection on ribbon

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, ribbon-control

The code below create dynamic menu with checkboxes. Each time the user must select the menu to select an item. I would like to avoid that and click only one time on the nenu.

Here the xml

```
<dynamicMenu id="MnuSelectOtherDB"
             label="Select Other Databases"
             getContent="GetContentCallback"/>
```

Here the VBA code

```
Sub GetContentCallback(control As IRibbonControl, _
                       ByRef XMLString)
    ' Callback get the selected datbases

    Dim lngDummy    As Long
    Dim strDummy    As String
    Dim strContent  As String
    strDummy = "<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft"
    strDummy = strDummy & ".com/office/2006/01/customui"">"

        For lngDummy = 0 To 5
            strContent = strContent & _
            "<checkBox id=""MyDynaCheckbox" & lngDummy & _
            """ label =""Dynamic Item" & _
            lngDummy & """/>"
        Next

    strDummy = strDummy & strContent & " </menu>"
    XMLString = strDummy
End Sub
```

Here screen shots

[image]

Here video of the issue
[Dynamic menu on ribbon](https://youtu.be/8gdPD8Owup8)

Comment: It would help to see a screenshot to see if you are referring to a ribbon tab and how checkbox double click renders.

Comment: Unfortunately, the design of the Ribbon does not support what you'd like to do. A menu is single selection, only, usually of a command that executes.

Comment: So the only solution wiil be to create a form.

Answer (score 0):

according to Cindy, ribbon control do not allow it. it's impossible for now!

Answer (score 0):

you can try Sendkey to re-expand the menu

```
    ' for my case ALT + Y2 then Y4 is shortcut key to activate element of CustomUI element
    Application.SendKeys ("%Y2Y4")
```

Comment: It works... but re-loading of dynamic menu gives flickering (collapse>re-expand)....

Answer (score 0):

"try this

```
Public GLOBAL_VARIBLE as LONG 
Public GobjRibbon as iribbonUI


Sub GetContentCallback(control As IRibbonControl, _
                       ByRef XMLString)
    ' Callback get the selected datbases

    Dim lngDummy    As Long
    Dim strDummy    As String
    Dim strContent  As String
    strDummy = "<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft"
    strDummy = strDummy & ".com/office/2006/01/customui"">"

        For lngDummy = 0 To 5
            strContent = strContent & _
            "<checkBox id=""MyDynaCheckbox" & lngDummy & _
            """ label =""Dynamic Item" & _
            lngDummy & "" onAction=""FUNCTION_TO_SET_GLOBAL"" getPressed=""YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME"""/>"
        Next

    strDummy = strDummy & strContent & " </menu>"
    XMLString = strDummy
End Sub



Public Function FUNCTION_TO_SET_GLOBAL(ctl as IRibbonControl)
GLOBAL_VARIBLE  = clng(mid(ctl.id,13))
GobjRibbon.invalidate
end function



Public Function YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME(ctl as IRibbonControl, ByRef Checked)
 Checked = (ctl.id = "Dynamic Item" & GLOBAL_VARIBLE)
end function
```